# Suggestion for Cassandra Data Model for Chat application

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I am currently developing a chat application on top of Cassandra.

A ***conversation***

- can happen between one or more users.
- can have more than one message.
- will be marked read if all the messages are read.

In an extreme case, conversation can have upto 100 users.

I want to solve the following query requirements.

- Show top n recent conversations for a given user.
- Show count of unread conversations (not messages) for a given user.

Any suggestions on Data Modelling?

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: 2.1.13 is the version I am using

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this structure :

```
CREATE TABLE conversation (
   conversation_id timeuuid,
   user_from varchar,
   user_to varchar,
   message text,
   message_read boolean,
   message_date timestamp,
   conversation_read boolean static,
   PRIMARY KEY ((conversation_id, user_to), message_date)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (user_from ASC, message_date ASC);
```

All your queries will be base on `conversation_id` and `user_to`. Message will be ordered by creation date. I think this structure can support the main purpose of a chat.

For the two queries, you need to have other denormalized tables like :

1) Show top n recent conversations for a given user.

```
CREATE TABLE user_message (
   user varchar,
   message text,
   message_date timestamp,,
   PRIMARY KEY ((user), message_date)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_date DESC);

SELECT message 
FROM user_message 
WHERE user = 'some user'
LIMIT 10;
```

2) Show count of unread conversations (not messages) for a given user.

```
CREATE TABLE user_conversations (
   user varchar,
   conversation_id timeuuid,
   conversation_read boolean,
   PRIMARY KEY((user), conversation_read, conversation_id)
);

SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM user_conversations 
WHERE user = 'some user' 
   AND conversation_read = false;
```

If you can use cassandra 3.X, you can use `MATERIALIZED VIEW` to manager data denormalization.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: 1) I think it doesn't support my use case. It gets top n recent messages. But I want top n recent conversations.

2) I think, it solves my purpose. Thanks!